# Merge multiple google sheets into a master sheet with script editor

Tags: merge, google-sheets

I am trying to merge multiple google sheets into one master sheet. There will be approximately 30 sheets that need to be merged. They will be saved in the same folder. The information is a call log for all the students in my building. I need them to merge into a master sheet to monitor progress and provide school wide analysis. Please help. Also, I am new to coding. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately your question only contains requirements - it is not showing any efforts from your side to solve this problem yourself. Please add your attempts to this questions - as this site is not a free "we do your (home)work" service. Beyond that: please turn to the [help] to learn how/what to ask here. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the welcome, and I apologize for not adhering to the question requirements. My attempts are minimal beyond opening the script editor and trying to find a code that will work. I did not think this was a free "we do your work" service site, but a place that may have provided some guidance. I will try some things, repost, and hopefully, someone can help me.

Comment: Are all of the sheets in exactly the same format?

Comment: Yes. Format is the same. It is a simple communication log for each teacher to use when providing positive feedback to parents. The master sheet will allow our principal to monitor the activity as a whole, instead of looking at each teacher's sheet individually. I appreciate any help or guidance you can give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a merge example I did for someone else.  You can add the sheets you want merged by adding to the array near the top.  It create a sheet called themotherofallsheets - yyyyMMddHHmm .  Most likely you'll want a refinement of this and perhaps sort the final results.

```
function concatAllSheets()
{
  var includedSheet=['Sheet1','Sheet2','Sheet3'];
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var allSheets=ss.getSheets();
  var sheetName='motherofallsheets-' + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyyMMddHHmm")
  var mother=ss.insertSheet(sheetName);
  for(var i=0;i<allSheets.length;i++)
  {
    var sht=allSheets[i];
    if(includedSheet.indexOf(sht.getName())>-1)
    {
      var rng=sht.getDataRange();
      var rngA=rng.getValues();
      for(var j=0;j<rngA.length;j++)
      {
        var row=rngA[j];
        mother.appendRow(row);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here's the code I linked to:

```
function myFunction() 
{
  var myFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("0B0kQD4hSd4KASUJKb2cya0NET1U");
  var spreadSheets = myFolder.getFilesByType("application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet");
  var newSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("Merged Sheets");
  while(spreadSheets.hasNext()) 
  {
    var sheet = spreadSheets.next();
    var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheet.getId());
    for(var y in spreadSheet.getSheets()) 
    {
      spreadSheet.getSheets()[y].copyTo(newSpreadSheet); 
     }
  }      
}
```

Comment: This is where I currently am at. I am having an issuesfunction mergeSheets() { 
}var myFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(SOURCE).next();
var spreadSheets = myFolder.getFilesByType(application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet);
var newSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.create(Sandbox);
  while(spreadSheets.hasNext()) {
    var sheet = spreadSheets.next();
    var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheet.getId());
    for(var y in spreadSheet.getSheets()) {
      spreadSheet.getSheets()[y].copyTo(newSpreadSheet); 
    }
  }

Comment: [This looks like it might be just what you need](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20620114/7215091).

Comment: I am getting the following error. Missing ) after argument list. (line 2, file "Code"). I am trying to pull the sheets from a subfolder titled "comm folders" inside another folder titled "Sandbox".

Comment: I tried the script you gave. I copied and pasted and changed the folder line to this:  "var myFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("comm folders");". I received the following error: "No item with the given ID could be found, or you do not have permission to access it. (line 4, file "Code")"

Comment: And now this: Script function not found: myfunction

Comment: Yes this does not look like an Id `DriveApp.getFolderById("comm folders");`

Comment: Do you know how to find the folder id? You can go to a folder and look at the url. It's a real long string of numbers and letters.

Comment: Thanks. I found the URL. I tried to run again. It appears to run without errors, but I do not know where the sheet is. No new sheet was created. Do I have  to publish it after I run it?

Comment: Look in the root.  Or just use drive to search for the name.  You don't have to publish it.

Comment: Found it thanks. The next question step. It does not appear to update my merge sheet when I type on either of the other sheets. Is there a way to adjust to make it have live updates? Also, is there a way to have it merge to one sheet, one tab?

Comment: Merging to one sheet or tab was what my original answer accomplishes.  It's the first section of my answer.

Comment: How would I adjust this line to instead of creating a new spreadsheet, I would add it into a previously created blank one?  /* Create the new spreadsheet that you store other sheets */  
  var newSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("Merged Sheets");

Comment: `The next question step. It does not appear to update my merge sheet when I type on either of the other sheets.` The spreadsheets are not linked to another.  It's just an independent copy.

Comment: Do I add your answer to the current script or erase and use the one you originally provided? Do I adjust to pull all from the specific folder? Also, thank you for your patience.

Comment: Since it is an independent copy, would I have re-run every time I'd like to look at most recent updates?

Comment: I suppose you would open it. [Here's the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app).

Comment: `Do I add your answer to the current script or erase and use the one you originally provided? Do I adjust to pull all from the specific folder?` Well,  they solve two different problems. So either run them separately or merge them together your choice.

Comment: `Since it is an independent copy, would I have re-run every time I'd like to look at most recent updates?`That's correct, they are not linked together.

Comment: Thanks. I will play around with this and see what happens. In the interest of not continuing to bother you, I will try to play around with this for awhile. Thank you for all your help... but expect more questions.

Comment: Note, there are limits to the size of an individual sheet.  And when I use the term sheet I'm referring to a tab.  I use the term spreadsheet to reference the entire file that contains many tabs or sheets.

Comment: No problem ask many questions.  Keep track of your research and integrate it into your next question along with whatever code you have.  And please it would be greatly appreciated if you would spend some time learning how to use our editor.  Taking advantage of the code display makes it much easier to read your code.  Check out the section on asking questions.

Comment: Thanks Cooper. I will do all that you suggested, including learning how to use the editor. This is literally my first attempt at all of this.

Comment: I'd appreciate it you would check off my answer.  Thanks